# Switching between images to avoid "jumping" behaviour

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to imitate the behaviour of a checkbox by switching custom checkbox images depending on the condition (true or false). I get a very annoying visual bug where as I set state to the truthy or falsy condition the images depending on it and the box does a little flickr before switching, here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import boxCheckedIcon from '../../../../assets/SmallBoxChecked.svg';
import boxUncheckedIcon from '../../../../assets/SmallBoxUnchecked.svg';


class Example extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            condition: false,
        }
    }


    handleSelect = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            condition: !prevState.condition
        }));
    }


    renderCheckbox = condition => {
        return condition ? <img
            id="checkedCheck"
            src={boxCheckedIcon}
            alt="checked check box"
        /> : <img
                id="uncheckedCheck"
                src={boxUncheckedIcon}
                alt="unchecked check box"
            />
    };

    render() {
        const { condition } = this.state;

        return (
            <div onClick={() => handleSelect()}>
                {renderCheckbox(condition)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

any idea how to make the transition between the two images smoother? CSS, React or otherwise..

Comment: The "id" attribute on the `<img />` element implies that there can only be one such checkbox at a time. I recommend you switch between `class="checkbox"` and `class="checkbox checked"` instead of `id="checkedCheck"` and `id="uncheckedCheck"`

Answer (score 3):

The most correct would be to move your images to a CSS-sprite and switch it background-position by an additional class

```
render() {
  const { condition } = this.state;

  return (
    <div
      className={classNames(
        'checkbox__icon',
        condition && 'is-checked',
      )}
      onClick={this.handleSelect}
    />
  );
}
```

In the example, I use the lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Comment: is there a way to avoid installing a lib for this? could it be done with content: attr(something); ?

Comment: `className` is a regular string. you can simple use the ES6 templates:

className={`checkbox__icon  ${condition ? 'is-checked' : ''}`}

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that every time you render different `img` tag, browser will fetch/download images again. Without using any font libraries, you can avoid this situation by rendering both images on the DOM and hiding/showing them based on condition:

```
renderCheckbox = (condition) => {
  return (
    <>
      <img
        heigth="40"
        width="40"
        id="checkedCheck"
        src={boxCheckedIcon}
        alt="checked check box"
        className={condition ? "" : "hidden"}
      />
      <img
        heigth="40"
        width="40"
        id="uncheckedCheck"
        src={boxUncheckedIcon}
        alt="unchecked check box"
        className={condition ? "hidden" : ""}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

and in your style.css file you can add **hidden** class:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-cloud-ylhcz).

Comment: @ksenia did this fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Create React App, you can use svg components instead of `img` tag.

```js
import { ReactComponent as Checked } from '../assets/checked.svg'
import { ReactComponent as Unchecked } from '../assets/unchecked.svg'

// Use it like this 
return condition ? <Checked/> : <Unchecked/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the dimensions on the image. Missing image dimensions could cause reflows because the browser has to load the image to see its dimensions and it will temporarily collapse the area used by the image causing everything below the image to jump around.